# Should I transform constraint optimization to unconstrained optimization?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have a two part question based on the optimization problem,

```
  max f(x) s.t. a <= x <= b
```

where f is a nonlinear function and a and b are finite.

(1) I have heard that if possible, one should try transform this constrained optimization problem to an unconstrained one (I am interested in not finding local maximums but this could also be to speed up the optimization). Is this in general true?

For the specific problem at hand, I am using the "optim" function in R with "Nelder-Mead" that uses non-differentiable optimization.

(2) Is there a "best" transformation to use to transform the constrained to  unconstrained problem?

I am using a +(b-a)*(sin(x)+1)/2 because it is onto and continuous (and so I am hoping not to find local maximums by searching the entire interval). 
See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75077/mapping-the-real-line-to-the-unit-interval for some transformations. The unconstrained problem is then,

```
  max f(a +(b-a)*(sin(x)+1)/2)
```

Also in the case of a one-sided constraint a < x, I have seen people use the exponential function a + exp(x). Is this the best thing to do?

Comment: `s.t. a < x < b` is not really a well-posed problem. We can only do `s.t. a <= x <= b`. It is better to use an algorithm that can handle bounds instead of reinventing the wheel (unless that is the purpose of this exercise). There are variants like BFGS-B that do this. Bounds are very useful in practice.

Comment: Thanks @ErwinKalvelagen. You're basically saying that for (1) I should use a built in function with constraints. BFGS-B is a derivative based method so not exactly what I'm after. I will use either nloptr or constrOptim (is there another function that is better for grid-based search with constraints?)... The exact a and b is not so important so a <= x <= b is fine (I'll modify).  Finally, in any case I'd be interested to know the answer to (2)

Comment: There is a paper by Rios and Sahinidis (Derivative-free optimization: A review of algorithms and comparison of software implementations) that gives a good overview of DFO solvers, including for bound constrained problems.